# Selenium 3.0.1 webdriver error for Firefox in Eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Ubuntu 14 and installed Eclipse with compiler compliance level 1.7 using selenium 3.0. If I decrease the level to 1.4, it shows me error on `sendkey()` function. I set the property:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/Rrrrr/Downloads/jars/geckodriver");
```

I use following code:

```
WebDriver driver;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/Rrrrr/Downloads/jars/geckodriver");

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

but it still gives me following error. Is it version problem or any other?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

Answer (score 0):

If by compliance level you mean Java version then you must set it to 8. Have a look at the [release notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) for *v3.0.0-beta1* where it says:

- Minimum java version is now 8+

Comment: thanks it is not version problem It is problem with my code sequence

Answer (score 0):

I Got solution over above code 
"Sequence of code is wrong"
Sequence must be as follows

```
 WebDriver driver;
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/Rrrrr/Downloads/jars/geckodriver");
```

driver = new FirefoxDriver();